# Counts based on matching values in the following record in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a dataset that looks as follows:

```
session_id    search_term    url            url_referrer        created_at    pagetype    rownum   
   ID1        SearchTerm1 <sitename>.com    <sitename>.com/a    2018-08-01     Search        1      
   ID1          <blank>   <sitename>.com/b  <sitename>.com      2018-08-01     ModPage       2      
   ID2        SearchTerm2 <sitename>.com    <sitename>.com/c    2018-08-02     Search        1      
   ID2          <blank>   <sitename>.com/d  <sitename>.com/b    2018-08-02     AxePage       2      
   ID3        SearchTerm3 <sitename>.com    <sitename>.com/e    2018-08-03     Search        4
```

This data is ordered by the field `created_at`, grouped by `session_id`. I would like to get a count of all the times a user searched for something (reflected in `search_term`) and also the count of times the users used the search results. In other words, I would like to match the `URL` of a record in a session with the `URL_Referrer` of the next record in the same session. When those URLs match, then we know that a user navigated to the next page using the search results displayed.

Also note that there may be sessions which didn't have any record after the `search_term` was searched. These are cases in which the user just closed the window and didn't navigate anywhere else. Such cases should also be counted.

For example - Let's focus only on rows 1 and 2. We can see that `<SearchTerm1>` resulted in a click because the `URL_referrer` for row 2 is the same as `URL` for row 1.

Similarly, let's focus on rows 3 and 4. The `url` or row3 does not match the `url_referrer` for row4. So this search did not result in a click.

I'd like the resultset to be in the following format:

```
Search_term    Num_Of_Searches    Num_Of_Matches
SearchTerm1           1                 1
SearchTerm2           1                 0
SearchTerm3           1                 0
```

Here's my incomplete query that I would like to complete, or any other query is also okay.

```
SELECT <insert here>
FROM t AS t1
  RIGHT JOIN t AS t2
          ON t1.session_id = t2.session_id
         AND t1.rownum + 1 = t2.rownum
         AND SPLIT_PART (SPLIT_PART (t1.url,'?q=',2),'&',1) = SPLIT_PART (SPLIT_PART (t2.url_referrer,'?q=',2),'&',1)
         AND (t1.search_term <> ''
          OR t1.search_term IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY t2.session_id,
         t2.created_at
```

This particular match on the join `SPLIT_PART (SPLIT_PART (t1.url,'?q=',2),'&',1) = SPLIT_PART (SPLIT_PART (t2.url_referrer,'?q=',2),'&',1)` is used for matching URLs and it's safe to assume that it works.

Any help would be much appreciated.